# .Net Regex Conditional Insertion

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code in a .cs file in Visual Studio

```
private Thing _a;
public bool Foo { get; set; }
public string Bar { get; }
```

I would like to replace produce the following using a Regex Replace

```
private Thing _a;
public bool Foo { get { return _a.Foo; } set { _a.Foo = value; } }
public string Bar { get { return _a.Bar; } }
```

So i did a Find and Replace in Visual Studio using this regex

```
(?<=public \w+\s)(\w+)\s\{ (?:(get);\s)(?:(set);\s)?\}
```

Which produces ...

```
private Thing _a;
public bool Foo { get { return _a.Foo; } set { _a.Foo = value; } }
public string Bar { get { return _a.Bar; }  { _a.Bar = value; } }
```

The Bar property gets an extra piece

> { _a.Bar = value; }

that isn't needed if capture $3 the set; isn't found. 
how would i go about doing this?

Comment: It looks like you've shown the *Find what* regex you have tried, but to be clear, what is the *Replace with* value that you tried with it?

Comment: Having said this, I think it is unlikely that you can do this in one find & replace because you are essentially trying to perform a conditional replace, which I do not believe is supported.